# Using MySQL session variable to increment a sort order / weight on Insert

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

Alright, my brain is a bit done for today and I might be approaching this completely wrong, so I'm hoping someone can give me a bit of insight on this.

I'm running an insert, through a loop in my code, though I'm wanting to use MySQL Session variables to increment the sort_order.

Maybe I'm just overthinking, any suggestions?  The table is recursive, so it does have parent/child elements, so doing something like `SELECT MAX(sort_order)` wouldn't work unless explicitly defining the parent id..which could work.  Well talked myself out of that one, still curious.

```
INSERT INTO another_table (some_field, sort_order)
VALUES
    (
        'some field value',
        (
            SELECT
                @sort_order := @sort_order + 1 sort_order
            FROM 
                (SELECT @sort_order := 0) so  
        )
    )
```

Comment: Would be helpful to show your table schema and some sample table data as it would be before insert and how you want it after insert.  It's not really clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: Don't dwell on the schema as much, think of it like inserting a parent page with a sort_order / weight of 1, then 3 of its sub rows as 1, 2, 3, then the next parent page as 2 and so on.

Comment: so, what's wrong with what you have?